# Extract partial string after a specific character and place in new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df in which I want to strip a string up to a certain character and then create a new column out of it.

```
a
John/Smith
```

becomes

```
a       b
John    /Smith
```

Thanks.

Comment: check str.split

Comment: Thanks!  Perfect.

Comment: @JustonLantrip But `str.split` won't preserve the leading slash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str.split`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["John/Smith"]})
df[["a", "b"]] = df["a"].str.split("/").apply(pd.Series)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
      a      b
0  John  Smith
```

Comment: Please check again, that doesn't look like OP's expected output

Comment: No need `apply(pd.Series)`,`df[["a", "b"]] = df["a"].str.split("/",expand=True)`